# Should we ask the proposed Web Design SE to merge with us instead?

Tags: discussion, web-design.se

[In our FAQ](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) it states:

> Graphic Design is for questions targeted toward design professionals,
>   students, and enthusiasts. This includes questions about: [...] Web
>   design

I just noticed (from an SE ad on our site) that there is [a proposal for a new Web Design SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58647/web-design). Would it be better for them to join us rather than set up a dedicated new SE site? If so, how do we do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a proposal in the commitment stage [reaches 45%](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200383/216955), the SE team gets together for a review to determine if it would translate to a healthy site. I've seen a handful of proposals shut down at this stage; they don't just allow every proposal to make it through.

It was brought up in the early stages of this proposal that this site is a duplicate of [Stack Overflow, Webmasters, Graphic Design, and UX](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11399/78536). Here's the response from the SE team once that stage was reached: [**The future of the Web Design proposal**](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/17362/78536). The overlap is specifically stated as a concern for the site:

> Our main concern is that it seems like the vast majority of questions for this site could already have a home elsewhere on the Stack Exchange network, something that has already been brought up on Area 51. Questions about HTML, CSS and the like are already welcome on Stack Overflow. Questions about designing for function (rather than form) fit on User Experience. For this site to work out, the answers for a given question will have to be at least as good as what the appropriate existing site would have produced.

For the moment, the proposal is not going to be merged with any site. They're going to give it a trial run in private beta to see how it works out, then potentially move to public beta. I don't think the questions asked in the site's [definition stage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58647?phase=definition) are all that stellar. Very few of them stand out as good questions that would be a good fit for Graphic Design, so it's difficult to determine exactly what the site's scope will be from that.

If the site gets shut down at any point, we can offer our site as a refuge for any decent on topic questions to be migrated here instead of erased from existence (this happened with one of the [Arduino](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino) attempts). That's the only sort of "merge" I can foresee happening at this point. But first, they'll get their fair shot at it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I believe so. Especially because if they start asking code questions, they'll get sent to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com). Web Design questions definitely on topic here, so they might as well join us.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not.

When I ask questions on here about web design it has not really gone over well with people telling me to ask on UX stackexhange or another site.

Graphic design and web design are not the same. Designing for the web has different considerations that are affected by technology, user demographics (children, blind, etc), and regulations. As opposed to designing a flyer or something else on illustrator.

Comment: To be fair, your questions about web design have pretty much all been very, very subjective. Color of this.. size of that... font choice... none of these are *really* on-topic due to the nature of the question.

Comment: @Scott people do not use websites subjectively, "ugggh the design is ugly but I could save money on buying auto insurance from this site." So yes even emotions and preferences are relevant to design. The tone of your comment seems that you feel that only technical topics about design should be "on-topic" at this site (like using photoshop), am I understanding your intent?

Comment: And what about [my question on illustrator](http://www.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38199/color-not-changing-in-illustrator/) that you helped out on? that was pretty technical and still got downvoted with no intelligent comment from the people that voted to close

Comment: That Illustrator question got down voted because you provided **no** possible information to assist. And it appeared to be tech support.

Comment: Agreed!  I'm actually here because I couldn't figure out why so many Web design questions were being asked in a Graphic Design forum.  Two similar but ultimately different things!